# device user mapping in mobile first platform 7.1 console while log in through adapterbased auhentication

Tags: android, authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am trying to create a login module from the tutorial and will be using the login user id as target in my next step :sent_EventBased_Push_notification

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/adapter-based-authentication-native-android-applications/

Done no changes just downloaded those sample project from github and run then in mfp and android studio as it is.And they did work wonderfully.

But in mobilefirst console though I saw the the device got registered there is no user id against it..What I mean is I am using a nexus4 to login and login id s 'my-phn-no'.So user Id should be 'my-phn-no'.

below I am pasting my AuthAdapter-impl.js [same as eg.]

```
function onAuthRequired(headers, errorMessage){
   errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null;

   return {
    authStatus: "credentialsRequired",
    errorMessage: errorMessage
};
}

function submitAuthentication(username, password){
if (username==="8907870678" && password === "password"){

    var userIdentity = {
            userId: username,
            displayName: username, 
            attributes: {
                foo: "bar"
            }
    };
    //WL.Server.sendMessage("Hello", "hi,gd mg")
    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", userIdentity);

    return { 
        authStatus: "complete" 
    };
    }

   return onAuthRequired(null, "Invalid login credentials");
  }

 function getSecretData(){
    return {
    secretData: "12345 changed for trial"
   };
  }

 function onLogout(){
    WL.Logger.debug("Logged out");
}
```

Can you please point out the part I am missing/how do I implement it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any error messages in server side logs, when you log in

Comment: no error.. I am checking message.log. There is no error.

Comment: Do I need to set up db for eclipse plugin / cli for mobile first foundation 7.1 ?

Comment: Do I need to set up db for eclipse plugin / cli for mobile first foundation 7.1 ? Is it because of that may be I'm not getting result?like :# For Oracle
#wl.db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SID

#wl.db.username=worklight
#wl.db.password=worklight

Comment: By default studio uses its own database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same code in SIT environment where it have the actual product installed MFP 7.1 . It worked perfectly .
I guess there is some thing going wrong in my eclipse plugin.